# `const_missing': uninitialized constant (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Every time I try to run any class from my rails 2.2 app's lib directory using "script/runner -e production ClassName.run" I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.2.2/lib/commands/runner.rb:47:  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:89:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant ClassName (NameError)"
```

For some reason I don't get this error when I run it as `test` instead of `production`, and everything works fine.

O yeah `run` is a class method i.e. `def self.run .... end`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That error occurs when ruby can't find a Class or Module.  I'd start out by:

1. Checking gem dependencies (are they same for all environments?)
2. Search your code for anything that defines ClassName, particularly Modules, Classes and plugins.
3. disable each of your plugins in dev, does any plugin suddenly cause that error?
4. if the code is in a lib add the lib require statement to your production.rb to force the lib to be loaded in production.

Hope that helps.

**update** Just to summarise the comments it was option 4.

Unless you only want to load the lib in production you should think about making sure all environments load the lib by doing one of the following:

1. Create a rails initializer (a .rb file under config/initializers) with the require in it
2. Add the path to the lib in config/environment.rb by enabling and modifying the config.load_paths variable.

Comment: That's the thing. The missing class in question is one that I've defined in lib. Even simple stuff like matching the classname to the file name checks out; in short it's defined. I don't know what I'm missing since it runs great on dev and
test just not production

Comment: Ah, that's interesting... OK one thing about moving to production is that things are initialised and cached in different ways to dev and test.  Where does the lib get called from?  Particularly see if requiring the lib in production.rb solves the issue.

Comment: I just call it from my app's root... I can't wait to test this out tonight; OMG if this is it that would be awesome

Answer (score 1):

I had multiple class definition(all STI classes) on the same file. and when I separated the definition into their respective files, It works